# Docker: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: not a directory

Tags: linux, docker

I am new to Docker, and don't know what is causing this error or how to diagnose it. Any specific help with this problem or tips on where to check first to diagnose this type of problem would be much appreciated!

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM java:8

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install maven

# Build foo
ENV curr /foo
WORKDIR $curr
ADD $curr/pom.xml /code/$curr
ADD $curr/src /code/$curr
RUN mvn package
```

When I try to build it with "docker build .":

```
...
Step 7 : ADD $curr/src /code/$curr
Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/236c9a1ac7edbd177f4718286f530cbba4ca275ec881be1e8fa3168e572843ac/rootfs/code/foo/.pivot_root774820419: not a directory
```

From what I understand, mkdir prints this when it tries to create a directory, but a file, symlink or socket by the same name already exists. But this seems to be some step internal to Docker, and changing the debug level didn't produce any useful output.

Comment: I do not see any `mkdir` in your Dockerfile, so it fails when trying to copy in non existing directories

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a `/` in `/foo`. In your configuration docker will put your `pom.xml` as `/code/foo` rather than, what I guess you intended, `/code/foo/pom.xml`. It then tries to add your source to your 'pom.xml' file which gives this error.

Try:

```
FROM java:8

# Install maven
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install maven

# Build foo
ENV curr /foo/ # <-- missing /
WORKDIR $curr
ADD $curr/pom.xml /code/$curr
ADD $curr/src /code/$curr
RUN mvn package
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, Docker raises this error also when we attempt to overwrite an existing file with an eponymous folder using Dockerfile `COPY` instruction!

In my case the application folder called `flask` was being copied by Docker (invoked by the Openshift builder) as usual using `COPY /flask /usr/local/bin/flask` and all worked fine until a new version of Flask dropped a file named `flask` in that very location, resulting in the same non-specific error message:

```
error: build error: Error processing tar file(exit status 1): Error setting up pivot dir: mkdir /var/lib/docker/overlay2/40221e791ab4c4d6d3610948703fe0eeb46618d6444a32e1bedcde3908ec5c7f/merged/usr/local/bin/flask/.pivot_root034225158: not a directory
```